# find duplicates in a sorted linkedlist in O(n) time

Tags: java, arrays, list, linked-list

What is the most efficient way do this? Is using iterator ok?

```
public class FindDuplicates {
    public static void main(String arg[]){
        int[] str={1 , 2 , 3 ,4  ,5 ,3 ,5 , 4,3,43,1,33,4,5};
        List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();

        for(int x : str) {   
            list.add(x);    
        }

        Collections.sort(list);
        System.out.println(list);

        Iterator<Integer> it = list.listIterator();  
        while(it.hasNext() && it.next() != null) { 
            /*   Pseudocode =>   if(it.next().equals(it.next.next)); */
            /* OR Pseudocode =>  if(it.next() == it.next().next) */ 
            System.out.println(it) ;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is the question? You want your code to be reviewed or something?

Comment: Try to define a variable called `int lastEntry`. If `lastEntry != currentEntry` then print currentEntry. This only works in a sorted list.

Comment: You could tell why you want to use `LinkedList` in a case where you are worried about performance? It is memory-inefficient (something like 8-16 bytes per list item), cache-inefficient (data all over the heap) and algorithmically limited (random access is *O(n)*), and useful only for some very special uses.

Comment: @StackUnderFlow Your approach is fine but your solution depends upon `collections.sort()` which has `nlog(n)` time complexity. Check my answer which gives you `O(n)` time complexity.

Comment: @Prateek That true about your collections.sort() ,but this operation will only be performed once (sort the list one time). which is still viable solution in terms of time complexity ."The better bad option"

Comment: @StackUnderFlow Doesn't matter if it is performed once or 10 times, the overall complexity of this approach would still be `Nlog(N)` For smaller size linked list the difference in performance would be negligible but when the size of list increases the difference in performance gets noticeable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to keep the previous value in a variable, should look similar to this:

```
 Iterator<Integer> it = list.listIterator(); 
 if (it.hasNext()) {
   Integer previous = it.next();
   while(it.hasNext()) { 
     Integer current = it.next();
     if (previous.equals(current)) {
       System.out.println("Dupe: " + current);
     }
     previous = current;
   }
 }
```

Note that you don't really need a linked list here (as others have pointed out already), you can just sort in place and then scan the array with a single loop:

```
int[] str={1 , 2 , 3 ,4  ,5 ,3 ,5 , 4,3,43,1,33,4,5};
Arrays.sort(str);
for (int i = 1; i < str.length; i++) {
  if (str[i] == str[i - 1]) {
    System.out.println("Dupe: " + str[i];
  }
}
```

If you don't want to change str, just keep track of the elements in a HashSet:

```
int[] str={1 , 2 , 3 ,4  ,5 ,3 ,5 , 4,3,43,1,33,4,5};
HashSet<Integer> seen = new HashSet<Integer>();
for (int i: str) {
  if (seen.contains(i)) {
    System.out.println("Dupe: " + i);
  } else {
    seen.add(i);
  }
}
```

If you consider the hashtable operations O(1), this also gives you linear time instead of O(n log n)

Comment: Here is how I did it with 0(n^2) time complexity                      ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.aslist(str));


for(String x : list){
  int count=0;
  for(String y : list){
    if(x.equals(y))
      count ++;
  }
  if(count %2 !=0){
    System.out.println(x );
  }
} 
}

Comment: The first code your wrote does the job perfectly , just tried it. Also the Hashset solution "very intuitive". Thanks for your time.

Comment: Output [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 33, 43]
Dupe: 1
Dupe: 3
Dupe: 3
Dupe: 4
Dupe: 4
Dupe: 5
Dupe: 5

Comment: just did , Thanks . Was not aware of this feature.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, note that you are using [Collections.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29), which is above O(n) complexity.

About your question: finding duplicates in a **sorted list** with O(n) complexity:

You can just have one variable that you set to the previous value you encountered, that way in the loop, you just compare the current value with that variable, then set the variable to the current value.

Answer (score 1):

A better way of doing it would be . Instead of [Collections.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) which is above `O(N)` complexity use a [Hash Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) unless you have a constraint on the `space complexity`. A basic pseudo code would be something like.

```
  if(set.contains(it)){// Check if it.info is in map or not
    System.out.println(it.info); // If it was then it is duplicate element hence print it
    }
  else{
    set.put(it);// Else if this is the first time you saw this element put it in set.
    }
```

This code has `O(N)` time complexity.

Comment: I see what you mean now . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] str={1 , 2 , 3 ,4  ,5 ,3 ,5 , 4,3,43,1,33,4,5};
```

you don't need to use `LinkedList` just to sort for finding duplicates. use `Arrays.sort(int[])` to sort your array and then scan: The following program will print the integer which has duplicates along with duplicates count:

```
int a[] = {1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3};

        Arrays.sort(a);

        for(int i=1 ; i<a.length;)
        {
            if(a[i] == a[i-1])
            {
                int j = i;
                for(; j<a.length; j++)
                    if(a[j]!=a[i])break;

                if(j > i)
                    System.out.println("Found duplicate: "+a[i]+" counted: "+(j - i+1));

                i = j;
            }
            else i++;

        }
```

**sample output:**

```
Found duplicate: 1 counted: 3
Found duplicate: 3 counted: 2
Found duplicate: 4 counted: 2
Found duplicate: 5 counted: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

All the forms with array, with list, with linked list.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void withArray() {
        int[] str = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 5, 4, 3, 43, 1, 33, 4, 5 };
        Arrays.sort(str);

        int previous = str[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < str.length; ++i) {
            if (str[i] == previous) {
                System.out.println("Duplicate " + previous + " and " + str[i]);
            }
            previous = str[i];
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void withList() {
        List<Integer> str = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 5, 4, 3, 43, 1, 33,
                4, 5);
        Collections.sort(str);

        int previous = str.get(0);
        for (int i = 1; i < str.size(); ++i) {
            if (str.get(i) == previous) {
                System.out.println("Duplicate " + previous + " and "
                        + str.get(i));
            }
            previous = str.get(i);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void withLinkedList() {
        LinkedList<Integer> str = new LinkedList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2,
                3, 4, 5, 3, 5, 4, 3, 43, 1, 33, 4, 5));
        Collections.sort(str);

        Iterator<Integer> it = str.iterator();

        int previous = it.next();
        int cur;
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            cur = it.next();
            if (cur == previous) {
                System.out.println("Duplicate " + previous + " and " + cur);
            }
            previous = cur;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        withArray();
        withList();
        withLinkedList();

    }
}
```